# If $(E, \varphi, F) \in D(A, B)$, then $(E, \varphi, F)$ is homotopic to the 0-module.

Tags: k-theory

I am reading proposition 17.2.3 Blackadar: 
If $ \varepsilon =(E, \varphi, T) \in \mathbb{D}(A, B)$, then $(E, \varphi, T)$ is homotopic to the $0$-module.

I have some questions about the proof.
We must find an element $ \bar{\varepsilon} = (\bar{E}, \bar{\varphi}, \bar{T})$ in $\mathbb{D}(A, B[0,1])$ such that $ev_{0,*}(\bar{\varepsilon})=(\bar{E}\otimes_{ev_{o}}B, \bar{\varphi}\otimes_{ev_{o}}id_{b}, \bar{T}\otimes_{ev_{o}}idB)$ is isomorphic to 0, and $ ev_{1,*}(\bar{\varepsilon})$ is isomorphic to $\varepsilon$,where $ev_{t}:B[0,1] \rightarrow B$, is the evaluation map

Because we need a  Hilbert $ B[0,1]$-module, we can consider $E(0,1]= \{ e:[0,1] \rightarrow E : e \ is 
 \ contionuous \ and  \ e(0)=0 \}$, which is a Hibert $ B[0,1]$-module.
we define a  $A$-action on $E(0,1]$ by  $(a · e)(t) = a(e(t))$ for all $a \in A,  e \in  E(0, 1]  \ and  \ t \in [0, 1]$. 
Define the operator Define $\bar{T} \in L(E(0, 1]), e → Toe$.

Could you please explain how   $ev_{0,*} = 0$ and $ev_{1,*} =\varepsilon.$
I think maby we can say that for example for  $E(0,1] \otimes_{ev_{0}}B$, if we consider $e(t) \beta\otimes_{ev_{0}}b= e(0)\otimes\beta(0)b =0$, where $\beta \in B[0,1].$

But how it gives us $E(0,1] \otimes_{ev_{1}}B = E$?

Comment: What book? What do the notations mean?

Comment: K-THEORY FOR OPERATOR ALGEBRAS
Bruce Blackadar proposition 17.2.3, which is related to the KASPAROV’S KK-THEORY